# Getting error in Google ChromeCast

Tags: android

I am using this code in `oncreate` method for `android` `chrome casting` and successfully setup and also played song

```
 mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusUpdated() {
            MediaStatus mediaStatus = mRemoteMediaPlayer
                    .getMediaStatus();
            isPlaying=mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;

        }
    });
```

and when stop song, i call this

```
 if (isPlaying) {
           mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause(apiClient);
       }
       else {
           mRemoteMediaPlayer.play(apiClient);
       }
```

But getting  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session` error.

Comment: Did you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273509/chromecast-android-sender-remotemediaplayer-producing-no-current-media-session

Comment: yes but i am not understanding that what he want to say exactly ..i used this in oncreate method... mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusUpdated() {
            MediaStatus mediaStatus = mRemoteMediaPlayer
                    .getMediaStatus();
            isPlaying=mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;

        }
    });  and also debug, but not going in this listener..