# Chromecast mRemoteMediaClient throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: No connection

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on Chrome-cast in android, I have migrate my Chrome-cast from SDKV2 to SDKV3.
RemoteMediaClient Throwing 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No connection'  when I am loading queue.

-Exception raised in this line

```
mRemoteMediaClient.queueLoad(mediaQueueItem,     PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER, MediaStatus.REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null)
                    .setResultCallback(resultCallback);
```

Here is the condition when this exception raised:-
Connect to Chrome-cast and after connecting load mediaQueueItem in the queue and it will work smoothly first time, Now Stop casting (disconnect Chrome-cast from device) and then I again connecting to the cast it will connected without any issue but after connecting load the mediaQueueItem for casting then it raised this Exception.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but can you try calling [requestStatus()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer) to verify connection? Also kindly check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273509/chromecast-android-sender-remotemediaplayer-producing-no-current-media-session), it might offer insight.

Comment: Thanx for your comment,
There are two requestStatus() that are available in CastSession and RemoteMediaClient, and I tried both but no one solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Caught my mistake that I was doing in `onSessionEnded()` method.

```
@Override
public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error)
{
     mRemoteMediaClient = null;
     mCastSession = null;
}
```

I was assigning null to `mRemoteMediaClient` and `mCastSession` in `onSessionEnded()`.
remove these two lines.

```
mRemoteMediaClient = null;
mCastSession = null;
```

There should not assign null when session is ended or session is suspended.

Hope it will help others.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem you described and does not solve it.

Comment: May not be, But my problem was resolved after doing this.
Your issue may be different.

Comment: This answer would only make sense to avoid NullPointerExceptions so I am rather sceptical

Comment: You should not sceptical, because it is not global solution for this issue. That was my issue, your may be different. If you find you did not get your answer, then you can ask your question with code snippet and specification, that will help you to find the right answer.

Comment: You cannot call `mRemoteMediaClient.queueLoad` on a null reference. This means mRemoteMediaClient was never null in the first place or you would have gotten a NullPointerException. So either your fix does nothing or there is some magic involved in the other parts of your class. I'm actually curious about this, could you post your full class?